# How to use #if helper in #each helper block

Tags: meteor

I have trouble with #each and #if helper.First  I am  looking for solutions in http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html,but I didn't find anything.
for example:
There are objects:

```
{
peoples:
 [{
    name:"A",
    age:16,
    sex:"boy"
  },{
    name:"B",
    age:14,
    sex:"boy"
  },{
    name:"C",
    age:18,
    sex:"boy"
 }]
};
```

In html (pseudocode,  i want  ,but i don't know how to  finish them.)

```
    {{#each peoples}}
            {{#if age equal 16}}
                {{name}} can drive
            {{/if}}
            {{#if age smaller than 16}} 
                {{name}} can't drive
            {{/if}}
            {{#if age  bigger than 16}}
                {{name}} can do anything
            {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

or

```
    {{#each peoples}}
            {{#if equal(name,"A")}}
                {{name}} can drive
            {{/if}}
            {{#if equal(name,"B")}
                {{name}} can't drive
            {{/if}}
            {{#if equal(name,"c")}}
                {{name}} can do anything
            {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use custom expression helpers.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getDriveStatus', function(age, name) {
  if (age == 16) {
    return name + " can drive"
  }

  if (age < 16) {
    return name + " can't drive";
  }

  if (age > 16) {
    return name + " can't do anything";
  }
});
```

and then,

```
{{#each peoples}}
        {{getDriveStatus age name}}
{{/each}}
```

And it is the same with character conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your time  , I got it. And according to your reply I just find a new solution

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function inside the Template.YourTemplate.helpers({}) section:

```
    Template.YourTemplate.helpers({
        'canDrive' : function(name, age){
        if (age == 16) { return name + " can drive" }
            if (age < 16) { return name + " can't drive"; }
            if (age > 16) { return name + " can't do anything"; }
     },
    })
```

In your template you can use it like this:

```
    {{#each peoples}}
        {{canDrive name age}}
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Prashant and @Oscar , I got the solution to the problem。
Their reply is helpful .If you have the same question,try to do them.
and there is  solution  without Handlebars.registerHelper:

In html:

```
    
       {{#each peoples}}
            {{#if equal name "A"}}{{age}}{{sex}}{{/if}}
       {{/each}}
```

In client:

```
    Template.test.equal = function (a,b) {
      return a===b;
    };
```

Comment: Cool! A suggestion: In examples, instead of using a, b put up the named variables like name, age, etc. Thanks for sharing.